# AWS Amazon IAM user Policy to access ONLY one EC2 instance on EU-WEST-1 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have read the AWS documentation and it wasn't helpful... at least not for me. I have read about IAM and the user policy on the EC2.

### I want to make users have full access/(or just some actions allowed) only on ONE ec2 instance.

The region I'm using is **eu-west-1(Ireland)**. I made this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{ 
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action":   "ec2:*", 
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:instance/INSTANCE_ID"
  }]
}
```

and when I login as the user, I see that I'm not authorized:

- You are not authorized to describe Running Instances
- You are not authorized to describe Elastic IPs
- You are not authorized to describe Volumes
- You are not authorized to describe Snapshots
- You are not authorized to describe Key Pairs
- You are not authorized to describe Load Balancers
- You are not authorized to describe Placement Groups
- You are not authorized to describe Security Groups

If I apply the following policy for the resource attribute:

> "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*"

it's Ok but it's not what I need because users have access on all EC2 instances.

I want to know if this is a bug of AWS or there are problems with eu-west-1 region or this policy isn't supported already? Or maybe I'm wrong, if so, please help me how to do

Comment: here is an answer but can't help for the eu-west-1: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548062/aws-iam-access-management)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recently introduced [Resource-Level Permissions for EC2 and RDS Resources](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/resource-permissions-for-ec2-and-rds-resources.html) are not yet available for all API actions, but AWS is gradually adding more, see this note from [Amazon Resource Names for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#EC2_ARN_Format):

> **Important** Currently, not all API actions support individual ARNs; we'll add support for additional API actions and ARNs for additional
>   Amazon EC2 resources later. For information about which ARNs you can
>   use with which Amazon EC2 API actions, as well as supported condition
>   keys for each ARN, see [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon
>   EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html).

You will find that all `ec2:Describe*` actions are indeed absent still from [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html) at the time of this writing.

See also [Granting IAM Users Required Permissions for Amazon EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html) for a concise summary of the above and details on *the ARNs and Amazon EC2 condition keys that you can use in an IAM policy statement to grant users permission to create or modify particular Amazon EC2 resources* - this page also mentions that AWS will *add support for additional actions, ARNs, and condition keys in 2014*.

### Possible Workaround/Alternative

Instead of or in addition to constraining access on the individual resource level, you might want to check into (also) using [Conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) combined with [Policy Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html#policy-vars-wheretouse), insofar `ec2:Region`is one of the supported [Condition Keys for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#amazon-ec2-keys) - you might combine your policy with one that specifically handles `Describe*` actions, e.g. something like this (untested):

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Region": "eu-west-1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that this would still allow the user to see *all* instances in `eu-west-1`, even though your original policy fragment would prevent all API actions that already support resource level permissions (e.g instance creation/termination etc.).

I've outlined yet another possible approach in section *Partial Workaround* within my related answer to [How to hide instances in EC2 based on tag - using IAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18646575/45773).

Good Luck!

Comment: Even with this simple policy, I don't get consistent result each time I CTRL+F5, and after a logoff/login. Sometimes I can list instances, but sometimes I get "You are not authorized to describe Running Instances"

Comment: I also tried replacing the "ec2:Region" condition, by "ec2:ResourceTag". I have only 1 instance with the correct tag, I keep getting "An error occurred fetching Instance data"

Comment: The workaround example wil fail because you cannot use conditions for EC2 describe actions according to the official documentation. Here is a list of EC2 actions that support conditions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html